# Spring security rest plugin: token based authentiction

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am trying to get successfully integrate [Spring security rest plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest)

But I am constantly failed,I am using the memcahed for token storage. Config.groovy Setup which I used to implement the plugin is :

```
//login end point url

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl='/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode='401'

//for  memcached
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useMemcached=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.hosts='localhost:11211'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.username=''
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.password=''
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.expiration=3600

//token generation
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useUUID=false
```

I making a request on `/api/login` via [Post man rest client](http://chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/index.html) with

```
{
    "username": "john.doe",
    "password": "dontTellAnybody"
}
```

json data but it gives me spring security  auth page's html in response, Am I doing some wrong configuration?Is there any futher configuration is required.I mentioned that I am using memcache for token storage.Any Idea will be helpfull for me.

**Edit**: please see the [logs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5trnz5k6w5ifmxs/logs?dl=0) file

**Edit2** : please check this [log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5trnz5k6w5ifmxs/logs?dl=0) file

Comment: Could you please enable debug output and paste it here?

I also need to see the full URL you used to make your request.

Comment: I have added the log file , please check and the url which I am using is `http://localhost:8080/restspring/api/login`, this is the post request with `{
    "username": "john.doe", 
    "password": "dontTellAnybody"
}` data.

Comment: @Álvaro Sánchez-Mariscal  I was using wrong configuration for memcahce .i.e `grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useMemcached=false` here I have given the false but It should be true and now it is working. Thanks for your time and such a nice plugin.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal I have implemented this plugin successfully in brand new project but when I integrate this plugin in an another grails project which uses ajax based login authentication it creates an issue, I have added the logs in question(Edit 2) please have a look.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal  Project in which I am facing issue is using `@Secured` annotation throughout the app, could this be a problem?

Comment: The key message in the logs is this line: `No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. Have you installed `spring-security-core` plugin **as well as** `spring-security-rest`?. Anyway, this latest issue you are experiencing seems totally unrelated with your original question. I suggest you to post a brand new question, providing all the details there.